# Why Flux.flatMap() doesn't wait for completion of inner publisher?

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor, reactive-streams, reactor-netty

Could you please explain what exactly happens in Flux/Mono returned by `HttpClient.response()`  ? I thought value generated by http client will NOT be passed downstream until Mono completes but I see that tons of requests are generated which ends up with `reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.PoolAcquirePendingLimitException: Pending acquire queue has reached its maximum size of 8` exception. It works as expected (items being processed one by one) if I replace call to `testRequest()` with `Mono.fromCallable {  }`.

What am I missing ?

Test code:

```
import org.asynchttpclient.netty.util.ByteBufUtils
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient
import reactor.netty.resources.ConnectionProvider

class Test {
    private val client = HttpClient.create(ConnectionProvider.create("meh", 4))

    fun main() {
        Flux.fromIterable(0..99)
                .flatMap { obj ->
                    println("Creating request for: $obj")
                    testRequest()
                            .doOnError { ex ->
                                println("Failed request for: $obj")
                                ex.printStackTrace()
                            }
                            .map { res ->
                                obj to res
                            }
                }
                .doOnNext { (obj, res) ->
                    println("Created request for: $obj ${res.length} characters")
                }
                .collectList().block()!!
    }

    fun testRequest(): Mono<String> {
        return client.get()
                .uri("https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_connection_pool")
                .responseContent()
                .reduce(StringBuilder(), { sb, buf ->
                    val str= ByteBufUtils.byteBuf2String(Charsets.UTF_8, buf)
                    sb.append(str)
                })
                .map { it.toString() }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create the `ConnectionProvider` like this `ConnectionProvider.create("meh", 4)`, this means connection pool with max connections 4 and max pending requests 8. See [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/resources/ConnectionProvider.html#create-java.lang.String-int-) more about this.

When you use `flatMap` this means `Transform the elements emitted by this Flux asynchronously into Publishers, then flatten these inner publishers into a single Flux through merging, which allow them to interleave` See [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) more about this.

So what happens is that you are trying to run all requests simultaneously.

So you have two options:

- If you want to use `flatMap` then increase the number of the pending requests.
- If you want to keep the number of the pending requests you may consider for example using `concatMap` instead of `flatMap`, which means `Transform the elements emitted by this Flux asynchronously into Publishers, then flatten these inner publishers into a single Flux, sequentially and preserving order using concatenation`. See more [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#concatMap-java.util.function.Function-) about this.